# Different outcome from seemingly equivalent implementation of PySpark transformations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a set of spark dataframe transforms which gives an out of memory error and has a messed up sql query plan while a different implemetation runs successfully.

```
%python
import pandas as pd
diction = {
    'key': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'f1' : [1,0,1,0,1,0],
    'f2' : [0,1,0,1,0,1],
    'f3' : [1,0,1,0,1,0],
    'f4' : [0,1,0,1,0,1]}
bil = pd.DataFrame(diction)
# successfull logic
df = spark.createDataFrame(bil)
df = df.cache()
zdf = df
for i in [1,2,3]:
  tempdf = zdf.select(['key'])
  df = df.join(tempdf,on=['key'],how='left')
df.show()
# failed logic
df = spark.createDataFrame(bil)
df = df.cache()
for i in [1,2,3]:
  tempdf = df.select(['key'])
  df = df.join(tempdf,on=['key'],how='left')
df.show()
```

Logically thinking there must not be such a computational difference (more than double the time and memory used).
Can anyone help me understand this ?

DAG of successful logic:
[image: successful]

DAG of failure logic:
[image: failure]

Comment: If you can share the sample data and dag that could be helpful in answering why this must be happening

Comment: @ScootCork is correct. The two actions are not logically equivalent for the reasons given. As such, you can't expect them to have the same query plan, behave in the same way on your cluster, or even produce the same result (except in the special case of a unique key in the data, in which case the result datasets will be the same, but the query plans will still differ).

Comment: I understand the query plans being different ,But the workload(time and memory used) increases more than 2 or 3 times.The computational workload shouldn't differ by so much right ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your use case is for this code, however the two pieces of code are not logically the same. In the second version you are joining the result of the previous iteration to itself three times. In the first version you are joining a 'copy' of the original df three times. If your key column is not unique, the second piece of code will 'explode' your dataframe more than the first.

To make this more clear we can make a simple example below where we have a non-unique key value. Taking your second example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'), (1,'b'), (3,'c')], ['key','val'])
for i in [1,2,3]:
  tempdf = df.select(['key'])
  df = df.join(tempdf,on=['key'],how='left')
df.count()

>>> 257
```

And your first piece of code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'), (1,'b'), (3,'c')], ['key','val'])
zdf = df
for i in [1,2,3]:
  tempdf = zdf.select(['key'])
  df = df.join(tempdf,on=['key'],how='left')
df.count()

>>> 17
```

Comment: I understand the differences, and the key is unique. I understand the DAG changing for the failure logic, but the computational workload shouldn't change right ?. Please take a look at my edited question with DAG.out of memory error happens when the data is big.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by computational workload? As the DAG's are different the Spark workload will also be different, it is simply more complex logic. Potenially the Catalyst Optimizer could optimize this logic better (don't know), that would be a different question.

Comment: By computational workload I mean when i run the more complex logic for a much bigger dataset, the memory required becomes 2x or 4x times causing an out of memory error.Even the above give example when run in databricks you can notice a clear 2x or 4x times more duration taken for the spark job.So i guess  my exact question is Why spark optimizer screws up in the second logic.Thanks for the reply.